# Load local CSS and JavaScript files when developing, live when pushed to server

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio

I am developing in Visual Studio and am making a lot of front-end changes to websites. But because of the server setup, every time I compile it takes one minute before I can see the changes in the browser.

Is it possible to use a program so that the website will load the site with local CSS and JavaScript files? I want to make changes locally and see the changes on the website without compiling the project.

Comment: Why you do not use a local http server and point it to your html/css code?

Comment: This really depends on how you have your project setup.  Most of the time you can just debug a web project and that will start an IIS debugging against your code, so you don't need to deploy.   What is your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for that. It allows you to map certain URIs to [different URIs](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/) or [local files](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-local/).

So you can tell it to load specific JS / CSS files from a different location (or use a wildcard and map them in bulk).

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is why you are developing a website with Visual Studio.

You should setup a local HTTP server and access your site from http://localhost.

Comment: Visual Studio is a fine tool for website development.  IF you are using .net in an IIS server.  It will spawn a local HTTP server and handle a lot of the busy work for you.

Comment: Which brings me to the next question, why would you want to develop using .net? :P I'm kidding. But still.